# Корректно ли использовано слово «быстрый»?

Tags: лексика

"Срок введения в действие нового закона не должен быть быстрым". Корректно ли здесь использование слова «быстрый»?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Срок с быстрым лескически не сочетается. Да и по смыслу непонятно, что это такое такое  "быстрый срок". Срок - он короткий или долгий.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, слово *быстрый* - не очень хорошее определение. Я бы написала: "Введение в действие нового закона не должно быть поспешным" или что-то в этом роде.

Answer (score 0):

Категорически нет. Здесь только "введение в действие" может(или не может) быть быстрым.